# Web login with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working on a dictionary attack (for testing purposes) on vsco accounts, I have successfully made one with python selenium with a 0.5 second delay between attempts, however I am trying to rewrite the program with remote login capabilities, I made a test account and captured the login post url: https://www.vsco.co/ajx/user/doLogin, the website login page is: https://www.vsco.co/user/login, the following code is what I am trying as a test to get the results of a successful login, however, with correct credentials, I am still unable to see any differences in the source code of the home vsco page or the /user/account page. If there is something I am missing or there is another way to do this remotely that would be great. (if it notices the "Share Your VSCO Profile" it would return yes, for you only see this page if you are logged in.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#https://www.vsco.co/ajx/user/doLogin
import socket
import requests
#url = 'https://www.vsco.co/user/login'
url = 'https://www.vsco.co/ajx/user/doLogin'
payload = {'login' : 'account_name', 'password' : 'mypassword'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url,data=payload,allow_redirects=True)
print(r.status_code)
p = s.get('https://www.vsco.co/user/account')
#print(str(p.text))
if('Share Your VSCO Profile' in str(p.text)):
        print('Yes')
```

Comment: "I am still unable to see any differences in the source code of the home vsco page or the /user/account page" differences between what? you can just print the html body and compared it with the source code from browser

Answer (score 0):

if you open up the web console on the login page, you'll see there's a hidden field in the login form. Also if you inspect the Post request, there's an extra parameter sent.

You can try to find and set those extra parameters with your post request.

An easier option might be using a headless browser instead of requests. (something like phantomJS with selenium python bindings)